# Xcode7 ios9 not supporting the armv7 and armv7s architecture devices

Tags: xcode6, ios9, xcode7, ios-charts

Following is the build settings for the ios-charts library integration.
My build settings for my app target and Chart target is as follows.

[image]

But it gives me following alert when I run app in Xcode7

[image]

Has xcode7 onwards stopped supporting the older devices

Note : I am using iPhone5 for testing which is running ios 8.4.1

Answer (score 1):

i have also faced the same issue previously. My device was with `iOS 8.4` and `Xcode` version is 7 (`Xcode 7`). I wanted to run app on device when it was connected but after a day of searching i was found that `iOS 9` consists of SDK version 9 (`iOS SDK 9`) which will not allow to connect or directly run app on devices which has os version less than iOS 9.

To run app, i have updated my device to iOS 9 & it is working like charm.!

Comment: But if I use carthage charts.framework it perfectly compiles to iphone5(8.4.1). This gives problem only when charts.xcodeproj is used.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. My problem also got solved after upgrading the device to ios9.

Comment: Some how when we drag the charts.xcodeproj it doesn't get linked properly that time we get these errors.